# Which Post-hoc analysis to examine group differences after linear regression model?

Tags: r, regression, post-hoc, lm

I have done a linear regression analysis in R (lm) to predict social unrest. I would now like to do a post hoc analysis to see if my prediction was more accurate for some countries / regions than others. What analysis in R would be feasible to examine this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The title suggests that you want to perform tests on coefficients; the text suggests you want to calculate prediction errors. More information is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compute the average prediction error (observed unrest - predicted unrest) by country/region. Smaller values would suggest more accurate predictions -- though only informally.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This was exactly what I meant!